# node.js variable undefined error after using typeof

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is my code

```
   if((typeof session) !== undefined && (typeof session.username) !== undefined){
        data = session.username+" online";  
        io.sockets.emit('update_common_message',data);

        socketsOfClients[session.username].push(socket.id);
    }
```

I am getting error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

I dont know what is the wrong with my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` returns a string, so you need to test against a string too:

```
if ((typeof session) !== 'undefined' ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this would suffice, looks cleaner too.

```
if (session && session.username) {
  data = session.username + " online";
  io.sockets.emit('update_common_message', data);

  socketsOfClients[session.username].push(socket.id);
}
```

Comment: so typeof is not recommend one to use check whether the variable or object is available or not ?

Comment: You can use `typeof` too. Try `if (typeof session !== 'undefined' && typeof session.username !== 'undefined') { // your code }`

Comment: do prefere to write less code when possible -- makes your code more readable, less error-prone. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `typeof` returns a string:

```
if((typeof session) !== 'undefined' && (typeof session.username) !== 'undefined'){
    // ...
}
```